# Google Apps Script - Is it possible to add an html sidebar to a particular sheet without using a menu, a button, or other user input?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to trigger the creation of a sidebar on a specific sheet? My Google Sheets (capital 'S') app has multiple sheets (lowercase 's'). When the user moves from the default sheet to this particular sheet, I want the sidebar to be visible. I know how to create the sidebar using a menu action or a button, but can it be done without user action? (other than the action of moving to the particular sheet).

Basically, I want the sidebar to be showing as soon as the user selects (aka 'clicks on', aka 'moves to') that particular sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with an `onEdit()` simple trigger or an "On Change" installable trigger.  However, there is no way for Apps Script to detect movement from one sheet tab to another.  So, the user would need to make an edit, or a change for the new sidebar to show up.

Then after the code triggers, you'll need to compare the active sheet tab name with a stored sheet tab name.

You can store values in Cache with `CacheService`.   Then you'd need to compare the current active sheet tab name with the value stored in Cache.  If there is a difference, then open the new sidebar.

```
function openSidebarIfNewSheet(e) {
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
  Logger.log('thisSheet: ' + thisSheet);

  Logger.log('e.changeType: ' + e.changeType);

  var storedSheetName = CacheService.getDocumentCache().get('sheetTabName');

  if (thisSheet !== storedSheetName) {
    CacheService.getDocumentCache().put('sheetTabName', thisSheet);
    //Open the sidebar


  };

};
```

Comment: That's what I found as well: some sort of user edit must occur. It would be nice if there were something akin to onFocus() to catch the change of the active sheet.

Thanks for the help!